# jQuery Array of Elements' Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From the given HTML, I am trying to extract the `pText` array, so that I end up with two `<p>` items (in this case), from which I can extract the two text strings `"link test1"` and `"link test2"`, and pop an alert for each of them. Why doesn't the below script work?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p><a href='/'>link</a> test1</p>
    <p><a href='/'>link</a> test2</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var pText = $('div').find('p');

for (i = 0; i < pText.length; i++) {
    alert(pText[i].text());
}
```

Comment: `$.map($('div p'), function(x) {return $(x).text()}).forEach(alert);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since that you're using jQuery, if you want to use the `.text()` method you have to extract a jQuery object and use `.eq(i)` instead of `[i]`, which returns a normal element.

Here's the correct code:

```
var pText = $('div').find('p');

for (i = 0; i < pText.length; i++) {
    alert(pText.eq(i).text());
}
```

---

Also, you can simplify your code using the `.each()` method (instead of the `for` loop), which calls a given function for every element of your jQuery collection (`pText`). In my opinion, it's easier, here you go:

```
var pText = $('div').find('p');

pText.each(function(i, el) {
    alert($(el).text());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`text()` is a function for jQuery objects.

Use it by wrapping your element in `$(..)`

```
alert($(pText[i]).text());
```

And a better way is to use `.each()`

```
$('div').find('p').each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using alert(pText.eq(i).text()); instead of alert(pText[i].text());

The jQuery code will be

```
var pText = $('div').find('p');

for (i = 0; i < pText.length; i++) {
    alert(pText.eq(i).text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#x').children('p').each(function() {
    alert($(this).text()); // "this" is the current element in the loop
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0q16d2h/)